# React.js application - making an area clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have my React.js application up and running, everything works as it should. By suggestion/request I was asked to add a sort of hidden button/area I can click to perform a specific task. It's not supposed to be a visible button, the suggestion was to make the current clock clickable (or a certain part of it).

First I thought I could just make a div, make it the size I want to and add a onClick to the div tag. It works, but it doesn't work quite as nicely as I'd like. It seems as if the clickable area extends outside of the div tag, which is real odd to me.

I added a simple border to the div tag to make sure it's not larger than I expect, but it's not. Yet, the clickable part is too large.

```
<div className="test" onClick={...}>Clock</div>
```

That's how I did my div. As I said, it works, but it doesn't quite work as I wanted to. So my question is in two parts: either if anyone knows why it seems as if my clickable area is larger than it should be (I've defined a width and a height in css, and I can clearly see the area thanks to the border) - or if anyone has done/know some similar solution to the problem. Can I define a certain area on a page and make it clickable? I don't want it seen, so it needs to be transparent and not get in the way of the rest of the application.

Thankful for all the suggestions I can get.

Comment: What's the point of an clickable element you can't see?

Comment: add  width  or height to the element larger

Comment: @Andy It's not supposed to be for anyone who's not aware of where it is. It's not the end of the world if a regular user presses it, but it's a function for people who knows it's hidden e.g. in the clock. May sound stupid, but it has its purpose.

Comment: @windmaomao I have already added a width and height to the div and confirmed its size by adding a border. Yet, for some weird reason, it's clickable outside the div.

Comment: @Kriistoffer, if you are using _React_, it will not allow you to click outside, unless you listen to the window event. Double check the div, and `box-sizing: border-box;`, sometimes this matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the case here may be [Event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing). If you are not familiar with Event Bubbling it means you may have an 'element' on top of 'another element' and your 'element' for example is clicked (or some other event happened to it) it will pass the event to its parent by default so your 'another element' will be like clicked. To see if this is the case or not, you can look for if there is 'any element' on top of your `div` element with className `test` and if any click handler attached to it. If so you can simply attach a `e.stopPropagation` method call on that 'any element' click handler

Comment: That definitely seems like the most likely answer, I've done some reading up now on it but it hasn't quite solved my situation. It seems to have improved slightly by changing up some code, but the parent div is still clickable.

I have some testing to do. Thank you for the suggestion and the help, appreciate it a lot!